# Network Response Time Out Error (create-react-native-app) (expo)

Tags: react-native, expo, create-react-native-app

I am trying to run create-react-native-app on expo app in android.

Firstly ,I created the project by writing command

> create-react-native-app test

then I executed

> npm start

then scanned the qr code from expo app.

But after scanning QR code , I am getting following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Java.net,sockettimeoutException: failed to connect to after 10000ms
```

[image]

Github Issue:

https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/144#issuecomment-296631692

Answer (score 117):

This is due to not open port from your machine.

#### Linux (Ubuntu)

In Ubuntu Run In terminal

`sudo ufw status verbose` 
To view open port if you cannot found 19000 port open then you need to open port using

```
sudo ufw allow 19000/tcp
```

and then again run

`sudo ufw allow 19001/tcp`

to serve http for react native i solve this problem in my ubuntu using this method. I hope this will help you.

#### Windows

To open a port in the Windows firewall for TCP access
On the **Start** menu, click **`Run`**, type **`WF.msc`**, and then click **`OK`**.

In the **Windows Firewall with Advanced Security**, in the **left pane**, right-click **Inbound Rules**, and then click **`New Rule`** in the action pane.

In the **Rule Type** dialog box, select **Port**, and then click **Next**.

In the **Protocol and Ports** dialog box, select **TCP**. Select **Specific local ports**, and then type the port number of the instance of the React port, such as **19000** for the default instance. Click **Next**.

In the **Action** dialog box, select **Allow the connection**, and then click **Next**.

In the **Profile** dialog box, select any profiles that describe the computer connection environment when you want to connect to the Database Engine, and then click **Next**.

In the **Name** dialog box, type a name and description for this rule, and then **click Finish**.

Similarly you can open port **19001** too.

Comment: I am on Windows 10

Comment: @YaShChaudhary i mention steps for windows too in answer

Comment: this is not working for me, I'm using Win10. do i need to do any additional step???

Comment: Does your mobile and pc both are in one network? @Ankit

Comment: Yes, I also tried with hotspots and virtual network but no luck

Comment: do it for 19001 also.

Comment: Work on Win 10 x64. Thanks!

Comment: The first part of the above answer is for *Linux* users. If you try to execute on windows it will return an error. Worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: this one works using `expo start --tunnel`

Comment: Omg, thank you so much. Worked very well on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: Update for Mac users: Uncheck "Block all incoming connections" in "Security & Privacy"

Comment: it's not working on win10

Comment: @KD.S.T. you are genius

Answer (score 105):

Change connection from LAN to tunnel.

[image: screenshot of what to change]

Comment: Alternately you can run `expo start --tunnel` from the terminal as well

Comment: Running `expo start --tunnel` worked for me! Unsure why this wouldn't be default for starting the development server. Seems vital for running dev builds on the device

Answer (score 51):

In my case the firewall settings alone didn't do it. My issue was that VirtualBox network devices were taking priority and the Expo host was starting on the wrong network.

On windows you can run `ipconfig` and look at the network adapters you have. `npm`/`yarn start` seems to take whatever shows up first in that list.

I found out about this from here: https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/60

If you don't need the other network adapters in the list, you can disable them in the Network Connections interface of the Control Panel.

If you need to use those connections *and* have Expo work then to solve the issue I followed [this process](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/adapter-priority-setting-unavailable-in-windows-10/d2b63caa-e77c-4b46-88b5-eeeaee00c306):

> 1. Goto Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network Connections
> 2. Right click the desired connection (Higher Priority Connection)
> 3. Click Properties > Internet Protocol Version 4
> 4. Click Properties > Advanced
> 5. Uncheck 'Automatic Metric'
> 6. Enter 10 in 'Interface Metric'
> 7. Click OK
>
> Repeat for the Lower Priority Connection, but this time put 20 into the 'Interface Metric'
>
> You'll now use the higher priority connection as a default.

Comment: https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/60#issuecomment-317104728

Comment: You can also use ipconfig to find out your wireless adapter's IP and use "export REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME='192.168.1.123'" to set to this IP. Worked for me.

Comment: Here is a more easier solution: Simply go to  Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network Connections and disable all VM network adapters and its done, re-enable them when you need the VM

Answer (score 21):

You can get around that by fixing your laptop's ip address to a static ip, let's say 192.168.1.69, then you need to change the react native packager ip address to the same of your laptop, using

```
set REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME=192.168.1.69 (Windows)
REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME=192.168.1.69 (Mac & Linux)
```

start your project again and you're good to go.

Answer (score 19):

I had done everything mentioned in context.
Just Changed my connected WiFi network from public to private.
This Worked for me

Answer (score 8):

[image]

First of all, disable the unused network connection. In my case it was VirtualBox. Maybe it's using the same port. I am not sure about that. after disabling the unused connections then restart the packager. if you used npm then type

```
npm start
```

Answer (score 4):

- Found ipv4 address
- open expo app then tap to explore button from bottom
- write exp://[ipv4adress]:19000 to searchbar
- Then your app will open

Answer (score 4):

change LAN to Tunnel to solve this issue

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you install expo application for react native, link to [official guide here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/installation.html)

```
npm install -g exp
```

Then you can use Genymotion software to emulate different environment setting for your app an run:

```
exp start
```

If you use in the terminal "npm start" with native react, the following is for you. 
I found out that if my application runs successfully IpV addresses of my computer, that are shown in the terminal and that is on Expo app are identical, for example:

```
ipconfig -> IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.124
exp://10.0.0.124:19000
```

Based on this observation I solved this issue by the following way:

1. Close npm prompt script which is running app
2. Close Expo app
3. Find your IP by running command in the terminal:

   ```
   ipconfig
   ```
4. Run command in NodeJS command prompt with your IP (for example 10.0.0.124)

   ```
   set REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME=10.0.0.124
   ```
5. Start Expo app, scan barcode

   ```
   npm start
   ```

   If it does not help, then use next steps recommended by React developers in addition to other reasonable efforts:
6. Install Genymotion with VirtualBox
7. SignUp at Genymotion site
8. Run Genymotion software and !!!SignIn

Answer (score 3):

If you are using git bash for development then this solution by Icruz4 will help

Instead of

`set REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME`

Use:

```
export REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME='192.168.1.123'
```

Note:

When you run

`npm start`

Expo tells you in the output the IP it's using. If that IP is not the IP you want then the

`REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME`

environment variable is not set properly

Comment: This solved the issue for me as instead of Cmd I was using Git Bash and the above command was not working for me

Comment: It's well explained in this comment: 
https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/144#issuecomment-308394689

Answer (score 3):

in Windows

1. run the `ipconfig` in command prompt
2. get the ip4 address and copy it.

Than go to

1. This PC > properties > advanced system settings > environment variables
2. add the following system variable: `REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME`
3. As the value for the variable I had to paste the ip4.

then run the `npm start`
It's work for me

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same issue. The problem is that the command yarn start or npm start finds the first enabled network adapter it finds which just happens to be the adapter for VirtualBox on my (and many other machines). The solution is to either:

manually set REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME environment variable, or
disable the unused network adapter in Windows' Network Connection (see image)
The problem is that Expo finds the first Network adapter, and not the active network adapter that provides the internet connection.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In case someone is still looking for the answer. Do the basic thing first, Disable the `VirtualBox Host-Only Network` first by opening your network configs. This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you have tried everything the other answers suggest and it still does not work, please also check that your computer and your phone are connected to the same WIFI network. For me this is what wasted an hour.

Answer (score 2):

[image: When i open Expo(Android application) for scanning the QR code i am facing same issue mention exactly same in the image.]

Solution 1:- **Connect both(your PC and mobile)with same network** then scan the QR with expo application.

Solution 2:-Select / **change connection type as Tunnel mention** in local host development window of your browser then scan the QR with expo application.

I think this will help :)

Answer (score 1):

This issue could possibly be resolved by:

[Setting your environment variable](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/60#issuecomment-356888536) with alternative instructions [here](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/144#issuecomment-308394689)

Or

[Assigning interface matrix priority for your network adapters](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/60#issuecomment-287081523) with detailed instructions [here](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/60#issuecomment-317104728) or [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/adapter-priority-setting-unavailable-in-windows-10/d2b63caa-e77c-4b46-88b5-eeeaee00c306).

Or

[An Ubuntu machine is unable to open a port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43593042/network-response-time-out-error-create-react-native-app-expo/44600431#44600431)

After you make any changes, please restart the computer before testing if it works.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I tried many solutions, only this way helped me to solve this problem:

In Windows:

- go to "Network and Connections" in Control Panel of windows (Network and Sharing Center>Change Adapter Setting)
- Disable all virtual boxes which you can see here
- Restart npm or yarn or expo...

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this problem occurred because Expo android app need "***draw over other apps***" **permission** and I didn't give it. So I give this permission to Expo app and the problem solved..

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest and 100% working solutions is:

1. Enable the Mobile Hotspot of your development machine( **PC or Desktop** ) and **connect your Android device** with this hotspot.
2. Goto Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network Connections
   You will land in here as shown:[Network Connections setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjbs6.png)
3. Then set the IP address of Local Area Connection(Your DESKTOP HOTSPOT) to a desired one, say: 192.168.1.69 by right-clicking on the concerned ***connection and then clicking on properties -> Internet Protocol Version 4(TCP/IPv4) -> Properties***. Then set the priority of this connection to be the highest and this is best described [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/adapter-priority-setting-unavailable-in-windows-10/d2b63caa-e77c-4b46-88b5-eeeaee00c306)
4. Then open a command terminal and run:

   ```
   set REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME=192.168.1.69 (Windows)
   REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME=192.168.1.69 (Mac & Linux)
   ```
5. Then restart your expo server by running **npm start** in your expo project folder and run the app on your Android device by scanning the generated QR code with the expo app.

Answer (score 1):

This error beaus your port it is not open
just check port is open or not for ubuntu you can check using the following way

```
sudo ufw status verbose
```

[image]
check  19000 port open then you need it
then run following command if port not open

```
 sudo ufw allow 19000/tcp
```

[image]
for other port runs following command

```
sudo ufw allow 19001/tcp
```

because http port not you are getting erro. above step solve your problem
similar for mac and windows check firewall setting once

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue I got this when I cancel the permission window of node js I solved it by going at the directory

1. On the Start menu, click Run, type WF.msc, and then click OK.
2. In the Windows Firewall and Advanced Security, in the left panel in Inbound Rules I had two options or rules disabled Node.js Serverside Javascript.

I simply double click and in new window In action, I select allow the connection and save

Answer (score 1):

Starting EXPO using the -- tunnel flag should help: `$ expo start --tunnel`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but after some [research](https://medium.com/@colin_78999/solving-network-response-timed-out-when-using-expo-on-windows-b486c22d5584), I found that this is because your computer has previously connected to multiple adapters. Expo may pick the IP address of one of these. To avoid this

1. Go to the command prompt and write 'ipconfig'.
2. Copy the IPv4 Address under Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi.
3. Then wrte the below command.

```
set REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME=(Your IP here)
```

Answer (score 1):

i just want to remember this for those who only try to scan the QR Code

***You need to connect your phone to your computer using a USB cable the first time you want to launch the app***,that will install the app on your device then the expo scan will work, i think all the solution above will work *maybe it's just because you didn't connect them first that everything didn't work*

just read the docs
https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device

Answer (score 1):

I got it by using this command on my ubuntu system:

> sudo ufw allow 19000/tcp

and then type this:

> sudo ufw allow 19001/tcp

restart vscode and the expo server and then you are good to go!

Answer (score 1):

For Linux Ubuntu 21.10

This is for users, that don't use UFW.

Make sure ufw is inactive, else, execute 'sudo ufw allow 19000'

```
sudo ufw status
```

List rules:

```
sudo iptables -L
```

This will output on clean Ubuntu like this:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Now allow port 19000 with command:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 19000 -j ACCEPT
```

Make sure that rule added:

```
sudo iptables -L
```

Expected output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:19000

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

After restart all rules will be wiped, so we need to install package, that will add rules from a file rules.v4 on each OS boot

```
sudo apt install iptables-persistent
su root
iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4
```

Enjoy! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Mac OS, this fixed it for me:

**System Preferences** > **Network** > **Wifi**

Uncheck "Limit IP Address Tracking".

[image]

This might have to do with iCloud Private Relay blocking your Mac from being seen by other devices.

Answer (score 1):

My problem is solved by navigating to my project folder and running the below commands:

```
expo start --tunnel
```

then start android app by typing

```
a
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows,

```
set REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME=my-ip-address
```

worked inside my git bash terminal, but not cmd. In git bash, after I ran npm start, I got a firewall popup, which I clicked allow and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

1. In your device: Log in to your expo app, create account if you doesn't have any.
2. In you system: open terminal go to you project directory via cd command and then type `sudo exp start`
   it will ask you your expo account login details once you done with this.
3. It will gives you qr code to scan.

Answer (score 0):

You Just need to open the port in Window Firewall and everything should work.

1.On the Start menu, click Run, type WF.msc, and then click OK.

In the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security, in the left pane, right-click Inbound Rules, and then click New Rule in the action pane.

In the Rule Type dialog box, select Port, and then click Next.

In the Protocol and Ports dialog box, select TCP. Select Specific local ports, and then type the port number of the instance of the React port, such as 19000 for the default instance. Click Next.

In the Action dialog box, select Allow the connection, and then click Next.

In the Profile dialog box, select any profiles that describe the computer connection environment when you want to connect to the Database Engine, and then click Next.

In the Name dialog box, type a name and description for this rule, and then click Finish.

Similarly you can open port 19001 too.

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried everything, and still not working for you. Change the Connection to 'Local' instead of 'LAN', it is working perfectly for me. It is not the best solution but does the work.

Answer (score 0):

It might sound very naive. But just restarting my machine solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after npm start script on windows environment.
Putting mobile on the same network as my Windows development environment was solved issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Change your network settings:**

1. Network and Internet setting
2. Status
3. Change connection properties
4. Checked public option

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**If everything fails then you can do this :**

1: Connect your android.

2: Open cmd and type

```
adb reverse tcp:19000 tcp:19000
```

3: Now

```
npx expo start
```

4: Enter this in the expo url manually of your android instead your ip.

```
exp://127.0.0.1:19000
```

Explanation:

The adb reverse command is used to set up reverse port forwarding from the device/emulator to the host machine.

In this specific case, the command adb

```
reverse tcp:19000 tcp:19000
```

forwards traffic from port 19000 on the device/emulator to port 19000 on the host machine. This is commonly used when developing mobile applications to allow communication between a mobile device/emulator and a local development server running on the host machine.

So, if there is a service running on port 19000 on the device, this command will forward that traffic to the same port on the host machine, allowing the service to be accessed from the host machine as if it were running **locally.**

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on Ubuntu, check your UFW status.

```
sudo ufw status
```

If it is inactive, enable it with

```
sudo ufw enable
```

Go back to your React native project and restart the metro builder scan the QR code. Everything should work unless you have some other issues(upgrade of expo ect) to deal with.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution for windows 8 and 10.

official support link - [SEE HERE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/make-a-wi-fi-network-public-or-private-in-windows-10-0460117d-8d3e-a7ac-f003-7a0da607448d#:%7E:text=public%20or%20private-,On%20the%20right%20side%20of%20the%20taskbar%2C%20select%20the%20Wi,profile%2C%20select%20Public%20or%20Private.)

> When you first connect to a Wi-Fi network, you can set it as public or private—depending on the network and what you want to do:

Private network. Use this for networks you trust, such as a network at home or work. When a network is set to private, your PC is discoverable to other devices on the network, and you can use your PC for file and printer sharing.

Public network. Use this for networks you connect to when you’re out and about, such as a Wi-Fi network at a coffee shop. Your PC will be hidden from other devices on the network, and you can’t use your PC for file and printer sharing.

Answer (score -1):

The only that I had to do to make it work was to connect the phone and my computer to the same network (before I was connected to two different service providers, I mean at home my laptop was connected to my home internet and my phone was connected to my mobile internet service).  I decided to just use the samea connection and it worked.