# Expo - Network Response Time Out Error (create-react-native-app) (Windows 10)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, create-react-app, expo

I have the exact same problem as here: [Network Response Time Out Error (create-react-native-app) (expo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43593042/network-response-time-out-error-create-react-native-app-expo). Every time I try to scan the QR code from my phone on LAN, I get the network response timeout error.

I've gone through every single response in both the linked stackoverflow post and the associated github thread: https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/144#issuecomment-296631692 to no avail.

Everything I've tried

- set REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME='my-custom-ip-address-or-hostname' with my static ip
- disable all connections aside from my wifi (The only other connection I had to disable was "Local Area Connection 4", I didn't have virtualbox like others)
- set my wifi connection to private
- completely disable windows firewall
- make exceptions to 19000, 19001, 19002 (entirely redundant given I disabled firewall, but I was desperate)
- restart computer multiple times
- use same network on phone as on computer
- put the line, `"android": "set REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME={your wifi ip address} && react-native-scripts android"` in my package.json

Note: A friend on the same network (also using a windows 10 laptop) got expo over LAN to work perfectly fine to his phone, so it's probably specific to my computer.

Note #2: Tunnel qr scanning works fine, but is painstakingly slow to reload so not realistic to use. Local brings me directly to "Something went wrong", no timeout error.

Comment: Could it be specific to your phone? E.g. Some Samsung phones have a "Secure wi-fi" app that blocks everything on a wi-fi unless you disable security for that specific wi-fi network.

Answer (score 9):

I wasted my whole day searching for answer and finally i got solution accidentally. Just change connection from **LAN** to **tunnel**

Below is the image,
[image]

Answer (score 0):

my case is to turn off any antivirus like ( Avast )